# ORA-00984 Column not allowed here with date in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00984

Im inserting values into this table

```
    CREATE TABLE Flight ( 
    FlightNumber         char(7) primary key,
    ArrivalAirportCode   char(6)   references Airport  (Airport_code),
    DepartureAirportCode char(6)   references Airport  (Airport_code),
    AircraftNumber       varchar2(25) references Aircraft (AircraftNumber),
    ArrivalDate          date,
    ArrivalTime          Varchar2(5),
    DepartureDate        date,
    DepartureTime        varchar2(5)
    );
```

and here are the values Im inserting into it

```
   INSERT INTO FLIGHT values
   ('CA3048',
   'LHR', 
   'EDI',
   'N859E',
   '14-NOV-2014',
   '22:15', 
   '14-NOV-2014', 
   '20:15');
```

And I get the column not allowed here error for the 2nd date I insert, but not the first one. I've tried putting quotes around the date but I just get another error.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but this data model / implementation has several flaws. Why are you storing ArrivalTime separately from ArrivalDate, and why are you using a string? The `DATE` datatype is perfectly capable of storing Dates with Times. Also, you're using the CHAR datatype - CHAR values are automatically padded with blanks, and this leads to all sorts of problems. Use VARCHAR2 instead.

Answer (score 7):

> '14-NOV-2014'

Why are you inserting a string in a **DATE** column? `'14-NOV-2014'` is a **STRING** and **NOT** a **DATE**. You should not depend on **implicit data type conversion**.

Always, convert the string into a DATE explicitly using **TO_DATE** and proper **format mask**.

For example,

```
TO_DATE('14-NOV-2014','DD-MON-YYYY')
```

One more thing,

> DepartureTime        varchar2(5)

Makes no sense. You already have a DATE column, a DATE would have the time element too.

**No need of a separate time column. A DATE has both date and time elements stored in 7 bytes.**

Oracle stores DATE in total of 7 bytes. Each byte in it stores values for an element of the DATE as follows:

```
Byte    Description
----    ------------------------------------------------
1       Century value but before storing it add 100 to it
2       Year and 100 is added to it before storing
3       Month
4       Day of the month
5       Hours but add 1 before storing it
6       Minutes but add 1 before storing it
7       Seconds but add 1 before storing it
```

All you need to do is just have **2 DATE columns**:

```
CREATE TABLE Flight ( 
    FlightNumber         char(7) primary key,
    ArrivalAirportCode   char(6)   references Airport  (Airport_code),
    DepartureAirportCode char(6)   references Airport  (Airport_code),
    AircraftNumber       varchar2(25) references Aircraft (AircraftNumber),
    ArrivalDate          date,
    DepartureDate        date
);
```

And then insert the values as:

```
INSERT INTO FLIGHT values
   ('CA3048',
   'LHR', 
   'EDI',
   'N859E',
   TO_DATE('14-NOV-2014 22:15:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
   TO_DATE('14-NOV-2014 20:15:00','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
);
```

**Update**

As mentioned in the comments by @GriffeyDog and @a_horse_with_no_name.

Alternatively, you could also the [ANSI literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51049) instead, for example:

```
timestamp '2014-11-14 22:15'
```

Comment: Or use the Oracle [date literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51049) syntax: `date '2014-11-14'`

Comment: @GriffeyDog I had to detail about the time portion, so didn't mention the date literal ;-)

Comment: Agreed, the OP shouldn't be storing the time separately.

Comment: To include the time in a ANSI literal, use `timestamp '2014-11-14 22:15'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, true. I was about to mention that.